# Listview only showing 1 result from query

Tags: android, database, listview

So I finally got my listview to display result(s) from my db query, but for some reason its only showing 1, the last.

```
public class PastGames extends ListActivity {

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.pastgames);



    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllFinalscores();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            String[] listData = new String [] {"Date: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Strokes: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + "Holes: " + c.getString(3)};
            this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.pastgames, listData));
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();


}
}
```

dbadapter

```
//***RETRIEVES ALL THE FINALSCORES***//
public Cursor getAllFinalscores()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_DATE,
            KEY_FINALSCORE,
            KEY_HOLESPLAYED},
            null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

Could someone let me know what I am doing wrong?  Why is it not displaying each row in the db?

EDIT:  Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

NEW (Correct way):

```
public class PastGames extends ListActivity {

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.pastgames);


    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllFinalscores();
    String[] listData = new String[c.getCount()];
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
    do {

        listData[c.getPosition()] = "Date: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
            "Strokes: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + "Holes: " + c.getString(3);
    }
        while (c.moveToNext());
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.pastgames, listData));
    }
    db.close()
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each row in your array your are setting ListAdapter in the loop. This why you only display the last one...

```
String[] listData;
do {
     listData[i] = "Date: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                        "Strokes: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" + "Holes: " + c.getString(3);
   }
while (c.moveToNext());
this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.pastgames, listData));
```

Fill your array in a while loop. And then call your this.setListAdapter() only one time. This will solve the problem

Comment: Could you please help me understand a better method of going about doing this? I think i see what you are saying... it sets "listData" goes to next and sets it all over again, etc. What would be a good way of avoiding overwriting it each time, and gathering all the information and then displaying it?

Comment: Fill your array in a while loop. And then call your this.setListAdapter() only one time. This will solve the problem

Comment: I gave you how it should be higher. Just create array of appropriate size and increment i yourself.

Comment: so it would look as follows??  Posted above @ end

Comment: Yes, just create an array of size equal to number of rows you have. And increment i every loop

Comment: Sorry to sound like an absolute idiot, but do you know of a good tutorial or explanation on how to do that?  I am really sorry - just very new to this all still. (i think i bit off more than i can chew!)

Comment: "create an array of size"

its currently X amount of rows... it all depends on how many times the user has saved, so it will always be growing.

Comment: How it will get bigger? You made a query, you know that cursor has 10 rows. So you create 10 element array for this. Got it?

Comment: each time the user saves data, it creates a new row in the database.
right now for instance i have 3 rows and 4 columns. once i save again I will have 4 rows and 4 columns... 5 rows and 4 columns.. etc.

so im guessing i will need to make the array = x

and then array++; each time it runs through? or something like that?

Comment: If you will query DB each time, then you will just create array each time and set it using setListAdapter()

Comment: I guess I just need to know, how to "resolve i" to a variable

i cannot be resolved to a variable

then at the end ill "i++"

Comment: I'm sorry, I know you probably want to smack me right now lol

Comment: 1) String[] listData = new String[c.getCount()]; 2) listData[c.getPosition()] = "Date: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" + .......

Comment: so instead it would look like that up top? (bottom area, i just edited it)

Comment: Sorry - I am trying very hard to stick with you but I dont think I know enough to say I am able to follow along correctly.

Comment: oh wait i think i missed the second part let me try that

Comment: It is working!!!! Thank you sooooo much!

I am so sorry to have put you through that.  I will make sure I take something away from this though.. Seriously, thanks a million for sticking with me!  Its perfect!

Comment: Welcome. Just try to make a progress and help others after that

Comment: Hi guys, please refrain from using the commenting system as an ad-hoc chat. Instead, use the chat system (link at the top of the page.)

Answer (score 1):

You're reinitilizing ListData on evey loop execution

Comment: Could you please help me understand a better method of going about doing this?  I think i see what you are saying... it sets "listData" goes to next and sets it all over again, etc.  What would be a good way of avoiding overwriting it each time, and gathering all the information and then displaying it?